# Marco Polo for Windows

Tags: geolocation, context

[Marco Polo](http://www.apple.com/downloads/macosx/networking_security/marcopolo.html) is an Apple solution which "knows" where you are and configures your networking, printers, shares, proxies etc... Basically anything that can change when you change location.

Windows 7 has basic support for printers - but is there anything that can provide the same experience as Marco Polo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've also been looking for this kind of program.

The best I've found is [Jarvis](http://www.pennyworthproject.org/jarvis/). It is still in early stages of development but looks hopeful.

Answer (score 1):

Some of the software bundled with the wireless card/laptop can do this.   Dell QuickSet has the ablility to set default printers, change network config, etc when it detect a change to the network connection.  You can also have it run a program you designate, so you can script any other changes necessary, or launch a VPN client if you are not on the corp network.

I had a batch file for each envirnment that connected the appropriate shares for home/work/other, and also swapped out the hosts files to allow me to point outbound mail at an alias that would resolve to the correct SMTP server for whatever network I was on.